# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: issuse

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have samsung phone with MODEL SM-A750F
my ANDROID VERSION is 9
and I have this log

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a ‪276824056‬ byte allocation with ‪25165824‬ free bytes and 117MB until OOM, max allowed footprint ‪170196328‬, growth limit ‪268435456‬
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newUnpaddedArray(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.util.ArrayUtils.newUnpaddedCharArray(ArrayUtils.java:51)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.resizeFor(SpannableStringBuilder.java:145)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:378)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:548)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.append(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:230)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3219)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2219)
at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:861)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:800)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:8221)
at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:2138)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:7644)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964
```

My code is

```
 public static CharSequence c(android.view.ViewGroup r6, TextEmojiLabel textEmojiLabel, java.lang.Object r8, StringBuilder sb) {
     if (!getBoolTrue(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), "show_mod_groups_check")) {
         return sb.toString();
     }
     if (f(r6, r8, z)) {
         SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
         SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(getString(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), group_mod()));
         if (getBool(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), "show_mod_in_groups_color_picker")) {
             spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getIntfromKey(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), "show_mod_in_groups_color_picker")), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
         } else if (getBool(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), "participant_name_color_picker")) {
             spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getIntfromKey(textEmojiLabel.getContext(), "participant_name_color_picker")), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
         }
         if (getLanguage()) {
             String str = r8.A0N;
             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
                 spannableStringBuilder.append(str).append("").append(" - ").append(spannableString);
             }
         } else {
             SpannableStringBuilder append = spannableStringBuilder.append("");
             String str2 = r8.A0N;
             if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str2)) {
                 append.append(str2).append(" - ").append(spannableString);
             }
         }
         return spannableStringBuilder;
     }
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

I think This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.
I have no idea or why its out of memory. How to fix it?

Comment: You can use basic debugging, the minimum is, try brute force method and remove part of the code, execute the remaining code and check if you get out of memory issue, this way you can find out which part of the code is causing out of memory issue.

Comment: Android failed to allocate 27 megabytes  while trying to show a listview item. This is probably due to showing images in listview that are not properly released. I donot think that your source code is related to this.